# issue in running selenium grid on virtual machine

Tags: java, python, node.js, selenium

I am trying selenium Grid on VMs with vagrant. What I did is that I followd the step from here https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/Grid2, I defined a hub `sudo java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.41.0.jar -role hub`

and defined the node locally on the same VM `sudo java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.41.0.jar -role node -hub http://10.0.2.2:4444/grid/register` in which `http://10.0.2.2:4444/` is the private IP of the VM in order to register node with hub.

My problem is that when I want to run a selenium test which is in python I get this error:

```
Exception: <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
<title>Error 500 org.openqa.grid.common.exception.GridException: Error forwarding the new session The server returned an error : Failed to start new browser session: org.openqa.selenium.server.RemoteCommandException: Error while launching browser</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>HTTP ERROR: 500</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /selenium-server/driver/. Reason:
<pre>    org.openqa.grid.common.exception.GridException: Error forwarding the new session The server returned an error : Failed to start new browser session: org.openqa.selenium.server.RemoteCommandException: Error while launching browser</pre></p>
<hr /><i><small>Powered by Jetty://</small></i>
```

And also when I run it from browser with : `http://10.0.2.2:4444/selenium-server/driver/?cmd=getNewBrowserSession&1=*firefox&2=http://www.google.com​`

I get this error: `Error forwarding the new session Empty pool of VM for setup Capabilities`

I think the node cannot register to the hub, I also changed it to the public IP so I used something like `http://X.X.X.106:4444/grid/register`. but I still see the error. but when I try it outside of VM it works fine!! Any idea of how to fix selenium grid on VM.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to do the same (Grid + VMs), but I wasn't success.
 The problem is with connection between host and VM machines.
I think you should configurate your network connection on VirtualBox as Bridge:
[Bridged networking](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_bridged)